# How cluster ip service works in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-service

Hi I am working in kubernetes. I have my front end and back end application. I have created deployments for front end and back end app. I created services using Cluster IP service as below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cep #### Insert your application service name here ####
  namespace: cep-dev #### Insert your application's namespace. Omit this line to use default namespace. ####
  labels:
    app: cep #### Insert your application service name here ####
spec:
  # Use one of ClusterIP, LoadBalancer or NodePort. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: cep   #### Insert your application deployment name here. This must match the deployment name specified in the deployment manifest ####
    instance: app
  ports:
    - port: 8080 #### Replace with appropriate port
      targetPort: 80 #### Replace with the port name defined in deployment
```

After going through some articles I have found cluster IP will expose pods within cluster so it will not be accessed outside cluster. But If I have ingress as below

```
- pathType: Prefix
          path: "/api"
          backend:
            service:
              name: cep
              port:
                number: 8080
```

So whenever requests comes with /api it will forward it to service cep. But my cep service is cluster ip service which is exposed internally. The  moment I have ingress I can access my service even though it is cluster ip service. Is my understanding correct? Can someone help me to understand this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/): `An API object that manages external access to the services in a cluster, typically HTTP.`. So it would still be correct the service is accessible only internally, since the ingress is sitting at the edge. You could think of it as a kind of reverse proxy, forwarding incoming requests to an internal component (=service).

Comment: Thanks Emile. So the moment I have ingress i can access service even though it is cluster ip service. So instead of having ingress which will expose all my services, can I have pod to pod communication? What I mean is I have deployed web app which will be accessed from https://abcdotcom which will call api located in another pod using any other mechanisam? With ingress i know

Comment: I'm unsure I understand your question correctly, but if your flow is `external user request -> web app -> API`, and API needs to be accessed from within the cluster only, then the only ingress you'll need is in front of the web app. Requests originating from the web app targeted for your API pod(s) should address a service with a selector pointing at the API application (and just make sure none of your ingress rules point to the API service).